# Floated Elements: Different Max-Widths on Different Screens

Tags: css, mobile

The main functionality of my site (http://kawaiiface.net) is stringent upon floats and max-widths working well. My sidebar slots are `float: left;` and `float: right;` , and my content buttons are `margins: auto;`. Everything positions itself in relation to one another responsively on desktop screen sizes -- but on *mobile*, the sidebars appear **above** the content.

In anticipation of the algo update, I've gone ahead and added responsive containers to everything: my sidebars run a `max-width: 160px;` with `width: 100%;` to 1. keep them in the spot they should be and 2. allow them to be responsive on smaller screens. This has caused an issue, though -- where the max-width allows my containers to fit well and provide a proper UE on desktop, they prevent the slots from expanding enough to fill the whole screen on mobile!

How can I remove my max-width parameter when my left-floated element is in its own block (aka above everything else on smaller screens)? [Here is an image to help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cukyO.png).

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear -- `float: center;` meaning `margins: auto;`. That is a sleep-deprived mistake, thanks~~

Comment: have you added a meta viewport? or any media queries?

Comment: I've not yet -- would you say that's my solution? Setting a new max-width once screen falls beneath a certain size?

Comment: just change the width of the containers within the media queries

Comment: I can provide an example if needed

Comment: If you could, that'd be very helpful -- what media queries (and breakpoints, I think they're called) would you recommend I use? + what css? Thank you so much!

Comment: i'll provide an example of a broad device media queries

Comment: let me know if it works i can add to it, if you provide code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of using `Media` queries

Helpful website: https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Example:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles for smartphones here */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles for smartphones here */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles for smartphones here */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {

/* Styles for ipad here */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {

/* Styles for ipad landscape here */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles for upad here */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
      /* desktops and laptops style goes here */ 
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles for large screen here *?
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {}
```

Add this to your css at the top, inside each `{}` you can change an element depending on the dimensions of the devices width. There are a wide range of varieties depending on the devices you're targeting but this is the broad spectrum.

Comment: I partially ended up using this, thanks! I found the breakpoint where things no longer floated correctly, and they used an @media parameter to redefine the slots as 100% only within that parameter. Things seem to be functioning more correctly now, THANK YOU!